# Can't install Open edX platform on Ubuntu Server via Vagrant & Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to run Open edX at my Digital Ocean droplet according [official instruction](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edx-Full-stack--installation-using-Vagrant-Virtualbox). But after `vagrant up` I have [such log](http://pastebin.com/Ff9vKinE): it goes to `Guru Meditation -4005 (VERR_VMX_UNABLE_TO_START_VM)`. Virtualbox extension pack installed.
What could be the reason of such error? At my home Ubuntu machine with same Vagrant and VirtualBox versions I successfully run it.

```
root@FabServer:~# vboxmanage --version
4.3.20r96996
root@FabServer:~# vagrant version
Installed Version: 1.7.1
Latest Version: 1.7.1
```

Comment: Full log from virtual machine pasted here http://pastebin.com/h3t6FqGG

Comment: Sorry, but I have 4.3.20 :)